# How to take an element after a re.compile?

Tags: python, hash, filter

**Using the "re" i compile the datas of a handshake like this:**

```
 piece_request_handshake = re.compile('13426974546f7272656e742070726f746f636f6c(?P<reserved>\w{16})(?P<info_hash>\w{40})(?P<peer_id>\w{40})')

 handshake = piece_request_handshake.findall(hex_data)
```

*Then i print it*

**I'm unable to add image because i'm new so this is the output:**

```
root@debian:/home/florian/Téléchargements# python script.py 
[('0000000000100005', '606d4759c464c8fd0d4a5d8fc7a223ed70d31d7b', '2d5452323532302d746d6e6a657a307a6d687932')]
```

**My question is, how can i take only the second piece of this data that is to say the "hash_info" (the "606d47...")  ?**

**I already tried with the group of re with the following line:**

```
   print handshake.group('info_hash')
```

**But the result is an error (sorry again i can't show the screen...):**

```
*root@debian:/home/florian/Téléchargements# python script.py 
Exception in thread Thread-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 552, in __bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "script.py", line 122, in run
    self.p.dispatch(0, PieceRequestSniffer.cb)
  File "script.py", line 82, in cb
    print handshake.group('info_hash')
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'group'*
```

This is the start of my full code for the curious:

```
import pcapy
import dpkt
from threading import Thread
import re
import binascii
import socket
import time

liste=[]
prefix = '13426974546f7272656e742070726f746f636f6c'
hash_code = re.compile('%s(?P<reserved>\w{16})(?P<info_hash>\w{40})(?P<peer_id>\w{40})' % prefix)
match = hash_code.match()
piece_request_handshake = re.compile('13426974546f7272656e742070726f746f636f6c(?P<aaa>\w{16})(?P<bbb>\w{40})(?P<ccc>\w{40})')
piece_request_tcpclose = re.compile('(?P<start>\w{12})5011')


#-----------------------------------------------------------------INIT------------------------------------------------------------

class PieceRequestSniffer(Thread):
    def __init__(self, dev='eth0'):
        Thread.__init__(self)

        self.expr = 'udp or tcp'

        self.maxlen = 65535  # max size of packet to capture
        self.promiscuous = 1  # promiscuous mode?
        self.read_timeout = 100  # in milliseconds
        self.max_pkts = -1  # number of packets to capture; -1 => no limit

        self.active = True
        self.p = pcapy.open_live(dev, self.maxlen, self.promiscuous, self.read_timeout)
        self.p.setfilter(self.expr)

    @staticmethod
    def cb(hdr, data):

        eth = dpkt.ethernet.Ethernet(str(data))
        ip = eth.data



#------------------------------------------------------IPV4 AND TCP PACKETS ONLY---------------------------------------------------           



            #Select Ipv4 packets because of problem with the .p in Ipv6
        if eth.type == dpkt.ethernet.ETH_TYPE_IP6:
            return
        else:

            #Select only TCP protocols
            if ip.p == dpkt.ip.IP_PROTO_TCP:
                tcp = ip.data

                src_ip = socket.inet_ntoa(ip.src)
                dst_ip = socket.inet_ntoa(ip.dst)

                fin_flag = ( tcp.flags & dpkt.tcp.TH_FIN ) != 0
                #if fin_flag:
                    #print "TH_FIN src:%s dst:%s" % (src_ip,dst_ip)




                try:
                    #Return hexadecimal representation
                    hex_data = binascii.hexlify(tcp.data)
                except:
                    return



#-----------------------------------------------------------HANDSHAKE-------------------------------------------------------------




                handshake = piece_request_handshake.findall(hex_data)
                if handshake and (src_ip+" "+dst_ip) not in liste and (dst_ip+" "+src_ip) not in liste and handshake != '':
                    liste.append(src_ip+" "+dst_ip)
                    print match.group('info_hash')
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow (and the rest of the Stack Exchange network)! You're question is actually better without screen-shots since the output of command line programs is plain text. Unfortunately, I don't know the answer off-hand but I thought this was a [very good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from a first-time user and it deserved an up-vote.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`re.findall()` returns a list of tuples, each containing the matching strings that correspond to the named groups in the re pattern. This example (using a simplified pattern) demonstrates that you can access the required item with indexing:

```
import re

prefix = 'prefix'
pattern = re.compile('%s(?P<reserved>\w{4})(?P<info_hash>\w{10})(?P<peer_id>\w{10})' % prefix)
handshake = 'prefix12341234567890ABCDEF1234'    # sniffed data
match = pattern.findall(handshake)

>>> print match
[('1234', '1234567890', 'ABCDEF1234')]
>>> info_hash = match[0][1]
>>> print info_hash
1234567890
```

But the point of named groups is to provide a way to access the matched values for a named group by name. You can use `re.match()` instead:

```
import re

prefix = 'prefix'
pattern = re.compile('%s(?P<reserved>\w{4})(?P<info_hash>\w{10})(?P<peer_id>\w{10})' % prefix)
handshake = 'prefix12341234567890ABCDEF1234'    # sniffed data
match = pattern.match(handshake)

>>> print match
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x7fc201efe918>
>>> print match.group('reserved')
1234
>>> print match.group('info_hash')
1234567890
>>> print match.group('peer_id')
ABCDEF1234
```

The values are also available using dictionary access:

```
>>> d = match.groupdict()
>>> d
{'peer_id': 'ABCDEF1234', 'reserved': '1234', 'info_hash': '1234567890'}
>>> d['info_hash']
'1234567890'
```

Finally, if there are multiple handshake sequences in the input data, you can use `re.finditer()`:

```
import re

prefix = 'prefix'
pattern = re.compile('%s(?P<reserved>\w{4})(?P<info_hash>\w{10})(?P<peer_id>\w{10})' % prefix)
handshake = 'blahprefix12341234567890ABCDEF1234|randomjunkprefix12349876543210ABCDEF1234,more random junkprefix1234hellothereABCDEF1234...'    # sniffed data

for match in pattern.finditer(handshake):
    print match.group('info_hash')
```

Output:

```
1234567890
9876543210
hellothere
```

Comment: Thanks for your time and your very good answer @mhawke , actually pattern.match seems to put known informations, the problem is that i don't know the datas in the handshake and i tried pattern.match(handshake) with handshake as my variable with all the datas but it output an error because match is expecting a String  :/

Comment: `handshake` is a list so you can't pass that to `re.match()`. Regarding "known data", do you mean that you do not know the prefix, `13426974546f7272656e742070726f746f636f6c` in your example?

Comment: I mean that actually my code is a kind of handshake sniffer, the prefix `13426974546f7272656e742070726f746f636f6c` is common to all handshake and permit to recognize them. He will be there all the time insofar as i act only when the packet is a handshake. 
However, the hash change wich each torrent and the peer id after the hash is almost never the same.
Regarding at this problem, i'm using a variable which contain the handshake data until another handshake give it its data.
@mhawke

Comment: `re.match()` matches from the beginning of the string, so the match will fail if your handshake data contains anything before the known prefix. If there is data before the prefix, and If there is only one handshake sequence in the sniffed data, you could try using `pattern.search(handshake)`. If, however, there are multiple handshakes in the sniffed data, try using `pattern.finditer()` instead. I've updated the answer to show use of `finditer()`.

Comment: `findall()` should also work if you have multiple handshake sequences in the same data string. You can use a for loop and indexing within the tuples to get the matched groups (as shown in first example).

Comment: Problem solved thank you very much for your time @mhawke, in my code `handshake` was actually `hex_data` i used your `match` and `group` advice and it works.

Comment: @flo: I am glad to hear that. Good luck with developing the rest of your code.

Answer (score 1):

`re.findall` will return a list of tuples. The `group()` call works on `Match` objects, returned by some other functions in `re`:

```
for match in re.finditer(needle, haystack):
    print match.group('info_hash')
```

Also, you might not need `findall` if you're just matching a single handshake.

Comment: Actually, re.findall() returns a list of tuples containing the matching named groups.

Comment: Ah, my bad, it seems you're right. I'm afraid I assumed too quickly that everything in `re` provides `Match` objects...